# Error starting Service Fabric Cluster (v 1.5.175)

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've been trying to install and start the new preview SDK, and even after several installs/uninstalls/reboots I always get this error when running DevClusterSetup:

Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)'.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:433 char:5

(full log below)
[image]

What I've tried, from other posts on stackoverflow:

1. reparing the performance counters with lodctr /R
2. used the system file checker with SFC /SCANNOW
3. checked that the windows firewall is running (and tried disabling it for the domain networks)
4. made sure I have enough disk space

The windows service "Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service" is always "Starting", but never starts.

I have two hints as to what the source of the problem might be, but can't solve it:

a) in the event viewer (Microsoft-Service Fabric > Admin) there are 4 errors that occur everytime the service attempts to start:

1. Unable to stop data collector for performance counters. The command
   "logman stop FabricCounters" failed with error code -2147287038.
2. System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.InvalidDeploymentException: Failed to
   start performance counter collection when creating or updating
   deployment
3. FabricDeployer::Install failed with error 0xffffffff
4. FabricDeployer::Install failed with error 0xffffffff, Rolling back

b) In the C:\SfDevCluster\Log\Traces folder there are files named something like FabricSetup-131034051696570691.trace . All of them have the same content, and in the middle there are warnings like these:

FabricSetup.FabricSetup.EventTraceInstaller,Method QueryDataCollectorSet failed with HRESULT: -2144337918

FabricSetup.FabricSetup.EventTraceInstaller,Method StopPlaTraceSession failed with HRESULT: -2144337918

and then further down the error:

**FabricSetup.FabricSetup.FabricDeployer,Configuration Deployment failed with error 0xffffffff**

If I go and check the Fabric deployer files (eg, fabricdeployer-635945286697202537.trace), I have a single error at the end, after a series of Performance counter deletes:

FabricDeployer.FabricDeployer,Executing command: logman stop FabricCounters

FabricDeployer.FabricDeployer,Unable to stop data collector for performance counters. The command "logman stop FabricCounters" failed with error code -2147287038.

but this error seems to come after some other error, as part of the rollback.

Any ideas? This is very frustrating and there is very little info on the net.
I've also tried cleaning the installation with ClearCluster.ps1 and installing the dev cluster to a different folder, always with the same result.

I am running Win10 with VS2015 Update 1, Azure SDK 2.8.2.1 . My user is a liveid which is local admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll start with a short answer to unblock you. From an elevated powershell session run:
Unregister-ScheduledTask FabricCounters

Comment: Matt, thanks for your answer, that fixed it. Can you clarify what was the problem? I was at it for over 5hrs of frustration. :-/

Comment: PS: I also suggest adding it to the troubleshooting pages, I bet more people had this problem: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-troubleshoot-local-cluster-setup/

Comment: Oh man, you saved my day. After few hours I found this discussion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent much time to try solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue but in my case the `FabricCounters` task wasn't there. So I did a search for other "Fabric*" tasks via `Get-ScheduledTask Fabric*` and found both `FabricAppInfoTraces` and `FabricQueryTraces` to be present still after uninstall.

I removed both Tasks using `Unregister-ScheduledTask <name>`, reinstalled the SDK and was able to start my local cluster again!